# Ruby rails with stripe and HostPay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm using HostPay a free web hosting shopping cart & CRM Platform. I would like to integrate Stripe payment gateway with this but unfortunately it is, as of now unsupported with HostPay. I have complete access to all the HostPay pages which are written in Ruby. One of the pages where the user pays the contents of the shopping cart using the chosen method. On this page is a variable written as: `<%= (basket.to_f_withvat).to_money %>` which holds the total price of the cart.

I was wondering if it was possible to use the value in this variable to send to the `$amount` var used in Stripe so users could pay the total of their different purchases as a one off payment. I know Stripe can integrate with other shopping carts such as Shopify to achieve this, and was wondering if it was possible in my setup. Unfortunately I have only just started learning Ruby so now sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to need to provide a more complete set of details to get an exact answer for your specific needs, but yes, Stripe will allow you use a variable to set the amount of a single charge.

You can find out more information in the Stripe gem: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby and in the Stripe Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges (you can see the charge amount in cents in the Ruby example on that page, that would get replaced with the value of your variable).

**Update**

I've taken the example code from Stripe and added your method to a variable, then we're passing that variable to Stripe.

```
# Your method here would need to return the correct value, in cents.
basket_total = (basket.to_f_withvat).to_money

# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"

# Get the credit card details submitted by the form
token = params[:stripeToken]

# Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => basket_total, # This is your value as a variable.
    :currency => "usd",
    :card => token,
    :description => "payinguser@example.com"
  )
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  # The card has been declined
end
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the Ruby syntax for replacing with my value in the variable.

Comment: Updated my answer with an updated example from the Stripe documentation I linked to. This example is contrived, but should give you an idea.